# How can use VolleySingleton in Android

Tags: android, android-volley

I want use `Volley` Library and `VolleySignleton` in my android application, but when startActivity, show me FC error.

**Activity codes :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
    private SlidingTabLayout mTab;
    private ViewPager mPage;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mPage = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPage.setAdapter(new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mTab = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTab.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        mTab.setCustomTabView(R.layout.custom_tab_view, R.id.tabText);
        mTab.setSelectedIndicatorColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        mTab.setViewPager(mPage);

    }

    public static List<Information> getData() {

        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5, R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8,
                R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image10, R.drawable.image11, R.drawable.image12,
                R.drawable.image13, R.drawable.image14,};

        String[] titles = {"Mohammad", "Nooshin", "Peyman", "Shaqayeq", "Nastaran", "Baran",
                "Aria", "BABA", "MAMAN", "Farzad", "Maryam", "Negar", "Omid", "Vahid",};

        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++) {

            Information current = new Information();

            current.title = titles[i];
            current.iconId = icons[i];

            ///----- fill to for (1000)
            /*current.title = titles[i%titles.length];
            current.iconId = icons[i%icons.length];*/
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }

    class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        int icon[] = {R.drawable.ic_menu_bookmark, R.drawable.ic_menu_toolbar, R.drawable.ic_cellphone90};
        String tabs[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);


        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

            tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);

            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(icon[position]);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 80, 80);
            ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(drawable);
            SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(" ");
            spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            return spannableString;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView txt_view;

        public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {

            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position", position);
            myFragment.setArguments(args);

            return myFragment;
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle saveInstanceState) {

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

            txt_view = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.fragment_text);

            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                txt_view.setText("Fragment is : " + bundle.getInt("position"));
            }

            RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://php.net/", new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Response" + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(request);

            return layout;

        }

    }
}
```

**VolleySignleton codes :**

```
public class VolleySingleton {

    private static VolleySingleton sInstance = null;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private VolleySingleton() {

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getAppContext());

    }

    public static VolleySingleton getInstance() {

        if (sInstance == null) {

            sInstance = new VolleySingleton();
        }
        return sInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
}
```

**MyApplication class codes :**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = null;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {

        return sInstance;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {

        return sInstance.getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

**FC error logs :**

```
01-24 12:38:53.264 26787-26787/com.tellfa.slidenerdmaterialtutorial E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.tellfa.slidenerdmaterialtutorial, PID: 26787
                                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context com.tellfa.slidenerdmaterialtutorial.MyApplication.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.tellfa.slidenerdmaterialtutorial.MyApplication.getAppContext(MyApplication.java:26)
                                                                                          at com.tellfa.slidenerdmaterialtutorial.Network.VolleySingleton.<init>(VolleySingleton.java:16)
                                                                                          at com.tellfa.slidenerdmaterialtutorial.Network.VolleySingleton.getInstance(VolleySingleton.java:24)
                                                                                          at com.tellfa.slidenerdmaterialtutorial.MainActivity$MyFragment.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:157)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                          at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
                                                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
                                                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
                                                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
                                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

How can i fix it and use this? i really need this. tnx all <3

Comment: Post your Mainifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `Manifest.xml`

```
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name="<package name>.MyApplication">
```

and change:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication sInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = MyApplication.this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {

        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

and

```
   mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getInstance());
```

Comment: oh yes, it's ok! tnx maaaan, i loveeeeeeeeeee youuuuuuuuuu :D